# Pages created on WordPress admin not visible in FTP

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, ftp

I was installing WordPress for the first time in cloud and uploaded Avada theme on it through WP admin dashboard and the document root in my 000-default.conf is /var/www/html and now I can see 2 WordPress installs in my FTP .. 1 is in /root folder where Avada theme is not present and and 1 is in /var/www/html and this has the Avada theme.. now all new pages that I am adding are not visible in Avada theme folder and I also tried updating apache2.conf and .htaccess file but no go..

I have the server as Ubuntu 16.04

I have not posted any code as I don't know what to attach so please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the pages you created from wp-admin are not real pages, those are the dynamic data stored in wordpress post table, and shown using page.php.

Comment: so can you please advise how to eleminate the 404 error that I am getting

Comment: seems your issues with the Permalink Settings. Go to settings menu and set the permalink once. Make sure that the .htaccess file should be writable.

Comment: Thanx , it is working but I am able to get the url's only on plain mode..How can I get the custom mode working as I want to have proper url's with blog  posts

Comment: in permalinks we have different options..like plain , day and name,month and name, Custom structure , etc.. And I was only able to get the plain mode permalink to work and these others were not working.. I want to have a url like abc.com/home

Comment: Custome Mode You need to place /%postname%/ or you select "Post name" option and then select Custom Mode and save it. Please make sure that .htaccess is writable.

Comment: Its still just working with plain settings only but maybe I am doing something wrong..thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 2):

You won't see WordPress "pages" in FTP; WordPress pages and posts don't exist as PHP or text or HTML files in a server directory. WordPress "pages" are dynamically generated by PHP in template files and from data (text entered in the WordPress post/page editor) in the database.

Try https://www.google.com/search?&q=wordpress+database+static+html+difference for more of an explanation.

Comment: I am getting 404 error when I am trying to access the url of the page so what can be the issue?